# Rails - How to move calculation from view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, view

Fairly new to RoR and wondering how I might move this one line of code out of my view and into my controller. I am also using devise and a current user is logged in. Thanks in advance

**profile.html.erb**

```
 <%= @profile.calorie / 4  %>
```

Ive set up a method called calculate within my **profiles_controller.rb** like so

```
 helper_method :calculate

 def calculate 
  ..... 
 end
```

Comment: what does this calculation represents?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't care for such a simple calculation in a view, unless you are using it in more than one place. Creating helper for this seems like an overkill.

Comment: So how might I translate that in a controller without a helper method?

Comment: @ssosina - Don't. It is fine to keep little calculations like that in a view. It is much better than creating new instance variable or method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the calculation in an instance variable in your controller and call it in your view:

```
<%= @new_calorie  %>
```

And in your controller action:

```
def show #or index
   @new_calorie = @profile.calorie / 4
end
```

Comment: It's because you haven't chosen a record of the object yet. If you just call `Profile` you're only calling the class, and not any individual records. You'll have to do something like `Profile.find(id: params[:id]).calorie / 4` in order to find the calorie of a particular Profile record.

Comment: Did **@calorie = current_user.profile.calorie** as i'm using devise. This worked. Thanks for your help